# How to separate Python list of strings using comma and ampersand depending length?

Tags: python, list

I want to separate Python list of strings using comma and  ampersand depending length.

For example

```
>>> my_list = ['a'] 
>>> foo(my_list)
a


>>> my_list = ['a', 'b']
>>> foo(my_list)
a & b

>>> my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> foo(my_list)
a, b & c
```

Comment: Can You give us example of list longer than 3 elements?

Comment: a, b, c & d (more than 3 elements)

Comment: Check my updated answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use following one liner:

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> ' & '.join(', '.join(l).rsplit(', ', 1))
'a, b & c'
```

It will [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) all the items with `', '`, then [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) from last `', '` and `join` again with `' & '`. It only works if your items don't contain `', '` though.

Comment: Be wary that if your list contains strings that can contain commas you might have problems with this solution

Comment: @Ben Comma by itself won't cause problems, only comma followed by whitespace which is the parameter for `rsplit`. Even then only the last item in the list will have this limitation, if you replace `'b'` in above with `'b, d'` you'd get `'a, b, d & c'`.

Comment: Indeed but that's an unacceptable limitation if you don't control the data

Answer (score 4):

```
ll = ['a']
length = len(ll)
if length >1 :
    output_str  = ', '.join(ll[:-1])
    output_str  = output_str + ' & ' +ll[length-1]
else:
    output_str  = ''.join(ll)

print(output_str )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but it is wrong with one value >>> ll = ['a']

Comment: @ShameemPKS, Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use len() function , Ex:

```
seperator = len(list) - 1
list[seperator].insert("&")
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.

```
def list_to_str(lst):
    remaining = len(lst)
    out = ""
    for item in lst:
        out += str(item) + " "
        remaining -= 1
        if remaining == 0:
            return out
        elif remaining == 1:
            out += "& "
        else:
            out = out[:-1]+ ", "
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
def foo(a):
    if len(a) > 1:
        return ' & '.join([', '.join(a[:-1]), a[-1]])
    if len(a) == 1:
        return a[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using python 3 you can use the more advanced unpacking:

```
>>> *a, b = ['a']
>>> ' & '.join([', '.join(a), b]) if a else b
'a'
>>> *a, b = ['a', 'b']
>>> ' & '.join([', '.join(a), b]) if a else b
'a & b'
>>> *a, b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> ' & '.join([', '.join(a), b]) if a else b
'a, b & c'
```

The unpacking stores all elements but the last one in `a` and the last element in `b` (empty list generates an error, but that's easy to deal with). This is exactly the partitioning of the special separator and can be elevated to join correctly.

You can do something similar in python2:

```
>>> lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> *a, b = lst[:-1], lst[-1]
```